# Setting Encoding in CSVHelper

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to set the encoding to `shift_jis`. I used the `Encoding.GetEncoding(932)` but it is not using the encoding when writing the file.

I am setting the encoding value using the Windows identifier 932 on the `StreamWriter` instantiation of the `TextWriter`. I see that the encoding value is set to `shift_jis`. When instantiating the the `CsvWriter` using the `TextWriter` object the encoding is getting lost. The encoding value on the `CsvWriter` is `UTF8`. See my code below how I am setting the values.

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileString, false, 
                                              Encoding.GetEncoding(932)))
{ 
   var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter, false);
   writer.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => false;
   writer.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

   .. write the columns 
   .. write the rows in a foreach loop

}
```

When I expand the Encoding properties on the textWriter it is set to `shift_jis`:

```
CodePage = 932
EncodingName = "Japanese (Shift-JIS)"
```

When I expand the Configuration/Encoding properties on the writer you it is set to `UTF8`:

```
CodePage = 65001
EncodingName = "Unicode (UTF-8)"
```

Could you please point out what I am doing wrong so I can write a file in `shift_jis`.

Comment: I believe you are saving it as `Shift-JIS`. I just tried saving the character `ｦ` to a csv file with `Encoding.GetEncoding(932)`.  When I looked at it with Notepad++ it showed the character `¦`.  If I changed the encoding Notepad++ was using to `Shift-JIS` it correctly showed `ｦ`.  CsvWriter may use `UTF8`, but when CsvWriter uses the StreamWriter to write the file, the StreamWriter's encoding will determine the file encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much David. Sorry about the delay in responding been swamped at work. I did verify the files did open in shift-jis using my code above.

Comment: the StreamWriter's encoding will determine the file encoding ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Yes, Encoding which is set in `StreamWriter` will determine encoding which is set when writing the file. [link](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/213)